# Rails Survey response form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a survey application that I confused on final side.
here is app models properties:

```
User

- Survey
    user_id

title
- Question
    title
    survey_id
    type: multiple_choice|check_boxes|short_answer
- Option
    title
    question_id

                   (Till here is okay. I can create surveys these includes more nested forms) Issue is after created surveys. (users responses) 

-Response
    user_id
    survey_id
-Answer
    question_id
    response_id
    option_id
```

Creating survey with nested attributes is okay. Problem is at Response side. how should be my response controller and response form on Survey show.html.erb?

There is response controller nested attributes below;

```
  def response_params
    params.require(:response).permit(:id, :user_id, :survey_id, answers_attributes:[:question_id, :response_id, :option_id ] )
  end
```

I should tell that survey can includes multiple questions these with only radio_buttons (independent radio buttons are other issue)

This issue made me so tired. I'll be glad if you can help me. Thanks.
For Source code: [Click for source codes](https://github.com/feedbackchain/TrueFeedbackChain)

updated files:

Response model:

```
class Response < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :survey
  has_many :answers, dependent: :destroy
  validates :survey, presence: true
  counter_culture :option
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :answers
end
```

Survey_controller:

```
def new_response
@survey = Survey.find(params[:id])
@response = @survey.responses.build

    # now, the tricky part, you have to build the Answer objects so you can use the nested form later
    @survey.questions.each do |q|
      @response.answers.build question: q
    end
  end



def create_response
  @survey = Survey.find(params[:id])
  @response = @survey.build(response_params)
  @response.user = current_user
  @response.save
end
```

Routes:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  devise_for :users
    resources :surveys do 
    member do
      get :new_response
      get :create_response 
    end
        end
  root 'surveys#index'

  end
```

form:

```
- # surveys/new_response.html.haml
- # You need to define a nested route inside survey resource to create the response
= form_for @response, url: create_response_survey_path(@survey) do |f|
  - # you can iterate over all the answers already initialized
  = f.fields_for :answers do |ff|
    - # get the question from the current answer to show the title and options and a hidden_field with the question id
    - q = ff.object.question

    = q.title
    = ff.hidden_field :question_id

    - # add the radios for each options for the question
    - q.options.each do |option|
      = label_tag do
        = ff.radio_button :option_id, option.id
        = option.title

  = f.submit 'Send'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wouldn't use the Survey's `show` action to show the form to create a Response, I think it's better to approach it as a `new_response` action to make it cleaner and leave the `show` action just to show the actual survey (not to respond it). Something like:

```
class SurveysController < ApplicationController
  def new_response
    @survey = Survey.find(params[:id])
    @response = @survey.responses.build

    # now, the tricky part, you have to build the Answer objects so you can use the nested form later
    @survey.questions.each do |q|
      @response.anwers.build question: q
    end
  end
```

Now, you can have a form for the response:

```
- # surveys/new_response.html.haml
- # You need to define a nested route inside survey resource to create the response
= form_for @response, url: create_response_survey_path(@survey) do |f|
  - # you can iterate over all the answers already initialized
  = f.fields_for :answers do |ff|
    - # get the question from the current answer to show the title and options and a hidden_field with the question id
    - q = ff.object.question

    = q.title
    = ff.hidden_field :question_id

    - # add the radios for each options for the question
    - q.options.each do |option|
      = label_tag do
        = ff.radio_button :choice_id, option.id
        = option.title

  = f.submit 'Send'
```

Your `response_params` should be something like:

```
def response_params
  params.require(:response).permit(answers_attributes: [:question_id, :choice_id])
end
```

note that I removed the `:survey_id` and the `:user_id`, you don't want a user to hack your form, change a survey_id or user_id and add responses to another survey made by another user!

and your `create_response` action:

```
def create_response
  @survey = Survey.find(params[:id])
  @response = @survey.build(response_params)
  @response.user = current_user
  @response.save
end
```

Hope it makes sense.

Comment: Thanks Brother. I am so glad because of you spend time for creating that answer. I will try and notify you. Other question is adding `user_id` to params. I added because i need users who responded to survey. Also some users(i.e: moderator)  can create survey and i need their user_id. But it will be recorded automatically by your solution. Am i true?

Comment: I'm setting it explicittly using `@response.user = current_user`. I don't think it's a good idea to make it a parameter fo the request since it can be changed by a malicious user. You should already have the current user loaded on the session, no need to make it a parameter of the request.

Comment: also i added to routes like; `get 'surveys/new_response' => "surveys#new_response"
` and path is working but path result is like : ` http://localhost:3000/surveys/new_response.7`  than i added also get method under surveys. result: `undefined method `responses' for nil:NilClass`
`@response = @survey.responses.build` (under new_response method in surveys_controller)

Comment: till the new_response.html.haml everythings are seems okay. I set routes and find parameters than it is okay. issue is on form. render  is   ` - q = ff.object.question` and
`undefined method question' for nil:NilClass  `

Comment: I'm not sure what's your current route, but I gues you have some `resources :survey`, right? add a block with `member do; get :new_response; end`, it will create a route with url `surveys/:id/new_response`, check the rails routing guide for more info on that. The `@response = @survey.response.build` fails because you had the wrong parameters and the controller can't find the survey.

Comment: `ff.object` should return the current Answer object on the iteration, it shouldn't be nil, I'm not sure what can be wrong there, you should update your question with your current code, it's a mess to follow everything on the comments

Comment: Answer is not created yet. that is why showing nil. also response should create the answers. (may be you missed out here)
[link](https://github.com/feedbackchain/TrueFeedbackChain)  that is my repository link if have time for check. I known that i made you tired :( sorry.

Comment: i updated question as current and added link for github source

Comment: I know the response have to create the aswers, that's why I do this: `@survey.questions.each{|q| @response.anwers.build question: q}` on my post, so `@response.answers` has answers built in to show the fields_for. What I see is that I have a typo there, it says `anwers` instead of `answers`. Maybe the look to build the answers is not right, doublecheck if `@response` does have the new answers for each question after that line

Comment: It is okay! thank you brother! excuse me if ı made you angry because of my questions. (Te debo una bebida :) )

Comment: Hahahah, sorry, I wasn't angry at all! hope you can make it work!